# How come my association bonus didn't count towards the league, but someone else's did?

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues, association, association-bonus

Looks like I've found a bug.

I've got 303 rep on Aviation, but it's showing me at 202 on the [Users list](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users).

I guessed the 101 difference was because association bonuses don't count, but it did for another user.

Here you can see I have 303 in the top bar, but 202 in the leaderboard (the assoc bonus didn't count).

[image]

Whereas for @Qantas 94 Heavy, the association bonus *did* count:

[image]

The rep's are off-by-101 in some cases, and are off-by-1 in others.

Comment: Caching. It's always caching.

Comment: @Krampus It isn't. It's been like that for a while, and it was caching quickly when I looking before hitting the rep cap.

Comment: A quick look at the API suggests this happens randomly (or at least I can't discern a pattern; it's included for some people and excluded for others), so maybe it's a race condition where sometimes the the association bonus is recorded microseconds before your account creation date and that messes things up? `</wild speculation>` Definitely odd.

Comment: @Krampus It's still the same, definitely not a caching issue: http://i.imgur.com/l6BXpYS.png I should be 4th, but I'm instead 9th.

Comment: @TimStone Looks like someone fixed something, thanks! The user "xpda" has the same issue too: missing 101 rep in the league.

Comment: @DannyBeckett "someone fixed something" -- cache cleared!

Comment: (heh, don't really know, just giving you a hard time)

Comment: @TimStone I've noticed that on http://aviation.stackexchange.com/users, the *week*, *month*, *quarter*, and *year* tabs all show the same [bad] data. *all* seems to show the correct data.

Comment: Another user has now posted about this over at Meta Aviation: [User list reputation bug?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/119)

Comment: Can confirm that it's always caching. I read a cached version of Krampus' comment and it said "Beer. It's always beer".

Comment: This was also reported on SO em Português: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/351/reputacao-sendo-mostrada-errada-no-ranking

Comment: `How come my association bonus didn't count towards the league, but someone else's did?` BECAUSE WE DON'T LIKE YOU, MAN. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 2):

The bug has now been confirmed by [@BretCopeland](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/231173/bret-copeland) on [Meta Aviation](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119/user-list-reputation-bug):

> For some users, including myself, the association bonus isn't counted for some reason. It must be a race condition based on when those values are first calculated for each user, but I can only guess as to the specific cause.
>
> The temporary solution is simply for reputation to be recalculated on the affected users, and there's a relatively easy way to do that. I tried this on my local development environment and it automatically corrected my rep, so I'll talk to someone about getting that fixed in production. Perhaps someone on the core team will also have an idea as to what's causing it in the first place.
>
> ---
>
> The rationale for why the starting 1 point is not included is that it is not really a reputation point, it's simply a minimum value and what our reputation counter starts at (instead of zero). It has no date associated with it - it's not even in the database - and therefore isn't considered part of any date range.