# Communities list is counting my reputation wrong on some sites

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar, communities-list

I have 101 rep on [Italian SE](http://italian.stackexchange.com) and am not suspended there. But the site switcher thinks I only have 1 rep there:

[image]

I noticed this after I [manually chose the sites to go in my switcher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215928/custom-ordering-for-stack-exchange-all-sites-dropdown).

To test this, I just added Expats and Reverse Engineering to my site switcher list. On both of those sites I have 101 rep and am not suspended. Results:

[image]

Huh?

Comment: The table we pull this data from says you only have 1 reputation. Who are you to argue with the raw data? How rude.

Comment: I saw a similar sight for a long time on a site where I had 101 rep. Visiting the site didn't fix it. When I earned 20 rep, it went to displaying 121 immediately, so it wasn't caching. I think it's somehow not counting the association bonus.

Comment: I assume [this is related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148646/152859), and the fix Nick made wasn't bullet proof and now the same bug causing it is back. @Anna what you think?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hmm. That does look related. Sounds like getting any rep event would fix things, but of course that requires site participation.

Comment: Related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212471/how-come-my-association-bonus-didnt-count-towards-the-league-but-someone-else

Comment: @3ventic No, that's different. Probably.

Comment: @AnnaLear any updates? [It just resurfaced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231994/reputation-does-not-match-in-a-beta-site), this time ordinary user, not SE employee.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Getting any reputation on the site will fix it (with the exception of the association bonus, apparently). This is fairly low priority on the assumption that most folks join sites to actually participate, so this will continue to resolve itself.

Comment: @Anna in the above case, the OP said it's suddenly OK now without him doing anything, and indeed there's nothing in his activity.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Then I'm probably wrong about association bonus not mattering.

Comment: @Anna nope, he got the bonus [three weeks ago](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/2685/cad?tab=reputation) and the rep in his "My Communities" list showed 101 [only today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231994/reputation-does-not-match-in-a-beta-site#comment763665_231994). Agree it's minor, but nothing like a good mystery, eh? ;-)

Comment: @Anna well, it also [affects the android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232193/association-bonuses) so maybe less minor than we thought?