# Reputation does not match in a beta site

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button, beta-sites, communities-list

In the new Software Recommendations beta site my reputation is 101, but in the Stack Exchange SiteSwitcher it is shown as only 1.

This image explains everything:

[image: Reputation discrepancy]

Comment: Caching? Something is stuck in a cache somewhere, I think I've seen this before.

Comment: The bug is in the communities list, everywhere else it's 101 already as far as I can see.

Comment: The bug has been there for several days, in several browsers, since I joined Software Recommendations. Now it is fixed :)
I am sure someone pressed a button somewhere...