# Why is my association bonus missing on certain sites on the app?

Tags: bug, reputation, android-app, association-bonus

I've recently started exploring some of the newer sites within the network, and notice that I haven't received the usual 100pt "association bonus" on all those that I have joined (Sustainability and Travel being two cases in point - I'd link to my profiles, but I'm using the mobile app and can't easily obtain links).

I'm not in the slightest bit bothered - am merely curious: what are the criteria for earning an association bonus?

---

**EDIT**

Okay, that's strange.  The problem appears to be in the Android app—last night a different bunch of sites were shown with only 1 rep, but right now it's just [UX SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

Comment: I can see your bonus on all sites. Where exactly you don't see it? Can you post link and screenshot?

Comment: Your [account list](http://stackexchange.com/users/310184/eggyal?tab=accounts) shows you have at least 101 rep everywhere except for one account where you spent 100 points on a bonus.

Comment: Are you *sure*?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/WdoV7.png from http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/1460/eggyal?tab=reputation and http://i.stack.imgur.com/HwB5H.png from http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13631/eggyal?tab=reputation both show association bonuses.

Comment: I suspect it got nothing to do with the app then but rather with the "My Communities" list, as [reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227129/the-site-switcher-is-counting-my-reputation-wrong-on-some-sites). Check the list in the desktop site and if indeed showing 1 as well, this one is dupe. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It is indeed showing as 1 in "My Communities", so I accept that this is a dupe.

Comment: Cheers, voted now and you can add your own vote.