# Showing different reputation in Stack Exchange Dropdown and on profile page

Tags: bug, reputation, communities-list

There are different reputations being displayed in Stack Exchange dropdown and in the right side of the header. Here is the image:

[image: screen shot showing reputation discrepancy]

I have seen other posts, but none of them are related to this. Why are there different reputations? It has been on for last few weeks. Is it a bug?

Comment: (Slow) Cache problem, maybe?

Comment: @Dawny33, It has been on for a while and I have also cleared browser cache, but it is still there.

Comment: It's not browser cache but server cache. Those two take the reputation from different places, and looks like the synchronization failed.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227129/communities-list-is-counting-my-reputation-wrong-on-some-sites (there it's something with association bonus though.)